# How to update UIProgressview in Tableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiprogressview

after i add UIProgressview into cell.contentview , 
how can i access to update Progressview on that cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold on to the pointer or set the tag and then find the UIProgressView object by the tag later.

Answer (score 0):

@Nick This sounds not to be good idea. Since some UITableViewCells may be reused by the UITableView for better performance, some rows may share a same UITableViewCell, in which case share a same UIProgressView. If you update the progress for some one row, it will also affect some other rows which share this table view cell.

No matter what, that's what I'm meeting now. What I'm gonna do is mark some flag in UITableViewCell to indicate by which row it is being used in the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```